# Using "self" in Python and wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I am currently reading a popular publication about wxPython.  In the code listed below, used to create 2 different wx.Frame subclasses, the use of "self" seems confusing and inconsistent to me.  The variables in the first code example have self in front of them while the variables in the second code example do not.  Why would one choose to use self and when would it not be required/appropriate.

```
class MouseEventFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Frame With Button',size=(300, 100))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel,label="Not Over", pos=(100, 15))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButtonClick,self.button)
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW,self.OnEnterWindow)
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW,
        self.OnLeaveWindow)


class InsertFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Frame With Button',size=(300, 100))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        button = wx.Button(panel, label="Close", pos=(125, 10),size=(50, 50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCloseMe, button)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnCloseWindow)
```

Comment: no self == [local variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable). `self.`... == [instance variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_variable).

Comment: The first code wants to keep a direct reference to the panel/button in those two attributes, the second does not.  Nothing deeper than that.

Comment: Oh ok.  Thank you.  So for the methods,  like self.Bind(...)  I assume self means something different?

Comment: No, self always means the same. Look it up in any good python tutorial.

Comment: Or RTFM: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects

Comment: In the language specification, it's hidden better, but tit's also there: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html, "Instance methods", "When an instance method object is called, the underlying function (__func__) is called, inserting the class instance (__self__) in front of the argument list". For python 2: When a bound user-defined method object is called, the underlying function (im_func) is called, inserting the class instance (im_self) in front of the argument list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general (this is a rephrasing of @roippi's comment), saying `self.panel = ...` makes it so you can access `self.panel` later on. It stores the data long-term. But if you typed `panel = ...`, you wouldn't be able to access a variable called `panel` outside of this method.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  So when "self" is used in Bind, i feel like it is saying "in this instance of the frame class, bind this to that".  Is that correct?

Comment: When self.Bind is used, Bind is a method inherited from wx.Frame.